# How to reissue shell prompt if only user input is enter?

Tags: c, shell, fgets

Im trying to make my own simple command line interpreter (shell) and I want the prompt to repeat itself if the only user input is whitespace. Essentially, if the user presses return, I would like the prompt to repeat and wait for the next input. I am using fgets to take input, and storing it in a char *commandBuffer for parsing by parse() method. I originally thought to check if there were arguments in argv(argc = 0), but this only causes the cursor to move to a new line without printing the prompt again. If I enter "\n\n\ncd" at the prompt, for example, cd still functions. Another problem I would like to try and fix is that in order to send whatever is typed at the prompt to the shell, the user must press enter twice. Here is my code thus far:

```
    for (;;) {
        printf("p2: ");
        fflush(stdout);


        /*---------FGETS PROMPT----------*/
        fgets(commandLine, STORAGE, stdin);
        ln = strlen(commandLine)-1;
        /* Removes trailing newline */
        if(commandLine[ln] == '\n')
            commandLine[ln] = '\0';
        /* ATTEMPT to repeat the prompt if only user input at prompt is enter*/
        if(commandLine[0] == '\0')
            continue;
 ....More shell code....
```

Comment: I have tried to implement my own console before too. You may want to try `libreadline` http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html It will make your life so much simpler.

Comment: Try checking for `ln == 0` in your if block instead of checking for `commandLine[0] == '\0'`

Comment: @ronmrdechai: That is a very minor optimization & would not lead to any change in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

(up to you to debug):
I always do something like this to survive any white space that comes along in a command. This also avoids problems if you get a \r\n\0 or just \r\0 at the end of incoming lines, which would cause your code fragment problems.

```
char  *cl;
for ( cl = commandLine; *cl && isspace(*cl); cp++ )
{
    if ( cl == 0 )
        break;          // escape for ( cl = ...) to get back to outer for (;;)

    // if trimming trailing white space in the same style is important:
    int   ln;           // length of non-blank text
  {                     // limit scope of cl2
    char *cl2;
    for ( cl = strchr( cl, '\0' ); cl2 >= cl; cl2-- )
        if ( isspace(*cl2) )
             *cl2 = '\0';
  }
  ln = cl2 - cl + 1;    // we can quickly calculate 

    ... do the rest of your loop here using cP as your start of text
}
```

The `*cl && isspace(*cl)` is a bit of paranoia left over from encounters with broken isspace() calls in historic times.